# How to use map composer in a stand-alone script?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to follow the [map rendering](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/composer.html) section from the pyqgis cookbook, but I'd like to test this as a standalone application. I can do the first part, using simple rendering, but I'm a bit stuck doing the second example using the map composer as a standalone script.

Here is a standalone example for the bit I can do:

```python
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

fh = open("eg.csv","w")
fh.write("""
x,y,name
153.0278, -27.4679, Brisbane
144.2500, -23.4500, Longreach
145.7753, -16.9256, Cairns
""")
fh.close()

uri = "eg.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "x", "y")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "eglayer", "delimitedtext")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
img = QImage(QSize(800,600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
color = QColor(255,255,255)
img.fill(color.rgb())
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
render = QgsMapRenderer()
lst = [ layer.getLayerID() ]  # add ID of every layer
render.setLayerSet(lst)
rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1)
render.setExtent(rect)
render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
render.render(p)
p.end()
img.save("render.png","png")
```

What I'd really like to do is the same, but use `QgsComposition`, and save as for example pdf. The cookbook says:

> When using composer in a standalone application, you can create your own map renderer instance the same way as shown in the section above and pass it to the composition.

This bit I couldn't do, all my attempts either get an empty map, or a segfault.
I'm running linux mint 13, using qgis 1.8.0. It would be great if someone could show me how to modify the simple example to one that uses the composer.

Answer (score 8):

**Based on the comments, this answer works for  versions prior to `2.4`**
For future reference, here is a working standalone example.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QgsApplication([], True)

fh = open("eg.csv","w")
fh.write("""
x,y,name
153.0278, -27.4679, Brisbane
144.2500, -23.4500, Longreach
145.7753, -16.9256, Cairns
""")
fh.close()

uri = "eg.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "x", "y")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "eglayer", "delimitedtext")
print layer.isValid()
layerset = []
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
layerset.append(layer.getLayerID())

myMapRenderer = QgsMapRenderer()
myMapRenderer.setLayerSet(layerset)
mapRectangle = QgsRectangle(140,-28,155,-15)
myMapRenderer.setExtent(mapRectangle)

comp = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)
comp.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
composerMap = QgsComposerMap(comp, 5,5,200,200)
composerMap.setNewExtent(mapRectangle)
comp.addItem(composerMap)
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("out.pdf")
printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(comp.paperWidth(), comp.paperHeight()),    QPrinter.Millimeter)
printer.setFullPage(True)
printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.Color)
printer.setResolution(comp.printResolution())

pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
comp.render(pdfPainter, paperRectPixel, paperRectMM)
pdfPainter.end()
app.exitQgis()
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a pdf, but it's blank.  I'm using 2.10 (I have to change .getLayerID() to .id())

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it no longer works for me either. Works on 1.8.0, but I just tested it on 2.4.0 and no longer seems to work.

Comment: Adding composerMap.setNewExtent(mapRectangle) seems to get it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on 2.8.3 anymore. I changed getLayerID() to .id() and still only get a blank page. Rendering of static text etc. works. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: QgsMapRenderer is deprecated in `2.4` and above, see this answer based on the same example which should work
http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/223127/36886

Answer (score 3):

QgsMapRenderer is deprecated in 2.4 and above, I've updated the deprecated part from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/70037/36886) to something that should work from `2.4` to `2.18.2`.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QgsApplication([], True)

fh = open("eg.csv","w")
fh.write("""
x,y,name
153.0278, -27.4679, Brisbane
144.2500, -23.4500, Longreach
145.7753, -16.9256, Cairns
""")
fh.close()

uri = "eg.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "x", "y")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "eglayer", "delimitedtext")
print layer.isValid()
layerset = []
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
layerset.append(layer.getLayerID())

def create_composition(layer_list, extent):
#New code for versions 2.4 and above
    ms = QgsMapSettings()
    ms.setLayers(layer_list)
    ms.setExtent(extent)
    comp = QgsComposition(ms)
    return comp, ms

comp, ms = create_composition(layerset, QgsRectangle(140,-28,155,-15))

comp.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
composerMap = QgsComposerMap(comp, 5,5,200,200)

#Uses mapsettings value
composerMap.setNewExtent(ms.extent())

comp.addItem(composerMap)
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("out.pdf")
printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(comp.paperWidth(), comp.paperHeight()),    QPrinter.Millimeter)
printer.setFullPage(True)
printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.Color)
printer.setResolution(comp.printResolution())

pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
comp.render(pdfPainter, paperRectPixel, paperRectMM)
pdfPainter.end()
app.exitQgis()
```

Comment: `layer.getLayerID()` doesn't works and must be changed to: `layer.id()`

Comment: @Mr.Che please include your OS and QGIS version

Comment: Win 7 and QGIS version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u8Ed.png

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code is helpful, though it's not a standalone application:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import os   
# Clear map canvas
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
# Open QGIS project
QgsProject.instance().setFileName('composerimage_demo.qgs')
QgsProject.instance().read()
# Set up composition
mapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
# Set dimensions and resolution
c.setPaperSize(160,185)
dpi = c.printResolution()
dpmm = (dpi / 25.4)
width = int(dpmm * c.paperWidth())
height = int(dpmm * c.paperHeight())
# Add map to composition
x, y = 0, 0
w, h = c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()
composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, x,y,w,h)
composerMap.setFrame(True) # Does not work with QGIS 1.9-Master. Use hasFrame() instead.
c.addItem(composerMap)
# Create output image and initialize it
image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
image.fill(0)
# Render composition
imagePainter = QPainter(image)
sourceArea = QRectF(0, 0, c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight())
targetArea = QRectF(0, 0, width, height)
c.render(imagePainter, targetArea, sourceArea)
imagePainter.end()
# Save image to disk (other extensions possible)
image.save('composerimage_demo.jpg')
# Clear map canvas
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

The map is based on a QGIS project. You can find a complete example here:
http://www.qgis.nl/media/2013/08/composerimage_demo.zip

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I don't know how to get a valid mapRenderer object to pass to `QgsComposition` without calling `iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()`.