# Labeling all features of shapefile with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a problem when trying to label all features of a shapefile with a Python routine.

If I open my shapefile in QGIS "by hand", and select a .qml with pre-defined label selection, the labels are correctly displayed. If I load the .qml file via a Python routine (see line below), all style features (colors etc.) are there, EXCEPT for the labels. No idea why.

`myLayer.loadNamedStyle("someStyle.qml")`

Since the line above did not give me the desired labels, I tried to create a more extensive routine, see below.

```
myProvider = myLayer.dataProvider()
myLayer.startEditing()
for myFeat in myLayer.getFeatures():
   #Some calculations in here...
   #The variable "Some_Value" is what I'd like to use as label

   Index_myLabelField=myLayer.fieldNameIndex("myLabelField")
   Value_myField={myFeat.id():{Index_myLabelField:QVariant(Some_Value)}}
   myProvider.changeAttributeValues(Value_myField)
   myLayer.commitChanges()

   myLayer.label().setLabelField(0,Index_myLabelField)
   myLayer.label().labelField(0)
   print myLayer.label().fieldValue(0,myFeat)   #Returns the desired label string

   #Create map renderer
   mapRenderer = QgsMapRenderer()
   rect = myLayer.extent()
   mapRenderer.setExtent(rect)
   mapRenderer.setLayerSet(QStringList(myLayer.id()))
   myRenderContext = mapRenderer.rendererContext()

   myLayer.select(myFeat.id())
   print myLayer.isValid()  #Returns true
   myLayer.label().renderLabel(myRenderContext,myFeat,1)   #Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Until the last line, where I try to render the label, everything seems to work fine.

What is going wrong in the last line?

There are two things I am unsure about:

1. In the QGIS API, the function to tell QGIS the field I want to use as label is

   setLabelField (int attr, int fieldIndex)

What is the "attr" in this context?

What should I put here?

I used "0" so far...

2. In the renderLabel() function, there is a "bool selected" needed in third position of the call. So what I am doing is selecting the feature (myFeat), and telling the function a "1" here.

Is that correct?

[Rendering and Labeling Shapefile with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84723/rendering-and-labeling-shapefile-with-pyqgis) does not fully help me, as the OP there does not seem to label all features of his shapefile. I am able to add one label to the shapefile (kind of like a title) with the described method there, but I am looking to have a label next to every feature (e.g. like street names on a map).

If you know why the qml-loading in the beginning of my post does not work can you let me know?

Comment: Standalone app or a plugin?

Comment: Standalone app, if I get the question right.

Comment: Yes as in your are making a application that runs out side of QGIS.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in your loop is needed

The only thing you should need to do is the following:

```
self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
self.canvas.mapRenderer().setLabelingEngine(QgsPalLabeling())
....
myLayer.loadNamedStyle("someStyle.qml")
```

**Note:** You should not use layer.label() as that is the old label system and is depreciated and unsupported.

Comment: Adding the line mapRenderer.setLabelingEngine(QgsPalLabeling()) to the code above did the trick. Thanks a lot!