# Layout show label and each polygon make serrated image

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I want to develop "Print lay out functionality", but in output system is giving me whole image, I want to print only selected polygon. Also it is not displaying label names on print image.

Please suggest some way.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import time
l = iface.activeLayer()

for a in l.getFeatures():
     attrs = {16: 1}
     l.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({a.id(): attrs})
     img = QImage(QSize(1280, 1024), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
     # set image's background color
     color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
     img.fill(color.rgb())
     # create painter
     p = QPainter()
     p.begin(img)
     p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
     render = QgsMapRenderer()
     palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
     palyr.readFromLayer(l)
     lst = [l.id()]
     render.setLayerSet(lst)
     render.setLabelingEngine(QgsPalLabeling())
     # set extent
     rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
     rect.scale(1.1)
     render.setExtent(rect)
     render.setScale(1)
     render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
     render.render(p)
     p.end()
     # save image
     img.save("C:/example/Ashwin/%s.jpg" % a['CHALTA_NO'],"jpg")
     attrs = {16: 0}
     l.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({a.id(): attrs})
     time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Comment: I note that you used `rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())`, this uses the entire area. You could use the extent of selection

Comment: when i am use rect = QgsRectangle(render.extent ()), it has giving me blank image.

Comment: Is your QGIS updated to last version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for each feature, use the QgsFeature().geometry().boundingBox() to achieve the rectangle. In your case, is a.geometry().boundingBox() and it returns a QgsRectangle() object

```
rect = a.geometry().boundingBox()
...
render.setExtent(rect)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help friend. I got my solution .Now the only issue is that in image I am not getting the labels, I have on polygon.
Please help in that too
Please see above attached screenshots here I need labels

Comment: Is your QGIS updated? Last version is 2.12.1

Comment: I have updated QGIS it's version 2.12.1-Lyon but it was making same polygon image it can not show length of polygon line and polygon Sr. No on label. for show label on image required any special code or not.

Comment: Sorry for my huge late in response. I think that your code isn't correct. Have you seen the example from: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84723/rendering-and-labeling-shapefile-with-pyqgis