# Filter MapComposer legend to only show layers visible on the map

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, legend

I have written a function in Python / PyQGIS (no standalone application, so copy/paste it to the Python console editor to run it) that takes a VectorLayer as argument, creates a MapRenderer object for that layer, then creates a MapComposer object using the MapRenderer, adds the map, a title and a legend to the composition and saves it as a png file.

Everything works fine except for the fact that the legend always includes all layers that are currently visible in the QGIS layer widget. What I like to have is to show only the layer in the legend that I passed to the MapRenderer (and then to the composition). See the following example.

That's what the QGIS layer widget looks like: Two layers are loaded, one is selected.

[image]

That is what the output image looks like when running the script below: Both layers from the layer widget are included in the legend instead of only the first layer (which is the only one visible in the plot).

[image]

This is my script. When trying to run it yourself, set the `plotdir` parameter at the top of it to match your desired output directory. The script does not load any layers, so this has to be done in advance.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

plotdir = r'C:\pyqgis_plots\\'

def saveImagesWithMapComposer(layer):

    print 'saving images with map composer'

    #######
    # set up layer set, extent and create a map renderer
    #######
    mapRenderer = QgsMapSettings() #new in QGIS 2.4 - replaces QgsMapRenderer()
    #mapRenderer = QgsMapRenderer()
    layerset = [layer.id()]
    mapRenderer.setLayers(layerset) #when using QgsMapRenderer, replace this with setLayerSet(layerset)
    mapRectangle = mapRenderer.fullExtent()
    mapRenderer.setExtent(mapRectangle)
    mapRenderer.setOutputSize(QSize(1600,1200)) #when using QgsMapRenderer(), setOutputSize needs a second argument 'int dpi'

    #######
    # create a composition and pass the renderer
    #######
    comp = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
    comp.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
    dpi = comp.printResolution()
    dpmm = dpi / 25.4
    width = int(dpmm * comp.paperWidth())
    height = int(dpmm * comp.paperHeight())

    #######
    # add map to the composition
    #######
    x, y = 0, 0
    w, h = comp.paperWidth(), comp.paperHeight()
    composerMap = QgsComposerMap(comp, x, y, w, h)
    comp.addItem(composerMap)

    #######
    # create label
    #######
    composerLabel = QgsComposerLabel(comp)
    composerLabel.setText(layer.name())
    composerLabel.adjustSizeToText()
    comp.addItem(composerLabel)
    composerLabel.setItemPosition(20,10)

    #######
    # create legend
    #######
    composerLegend = QgsComposerLegend(comp)
    composerLegend.model().setLayerSet(mapRenderer.layers()) #when using QgsMapRenderer, use layerSet() instead of layers()
    composerLegend.setTitle('')
    comp.addItem(composerLegend)     
    composerLegend.setItemPosition(20,20)

    #######
    # create image and initialize
    #######
    image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
    image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
    image.fill(0)

    #######
    # Render composition
    #######
    imagePainter = QPainter(image)
    sourceArea = QRectF(0, 0, comp.paperWidth(), comp.paperHeight())
    targetArea = QRectF(0, 0, width, height)
    comp.render(imagePainter, targetArea, sourceArea)
    imagePainter.end()

    # Save image to disk (other extensions possible)
    image.save(plotdir + layer.name() + '.png', 'png')

    return

###################################
# call function
###################################

# get first layer from the canvas and pass it to the plot function
layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
layer = layers[0]

saveImagesWithMapComposer(layer)

print 'finished'
```

I already tried using the deprecated QgsMapRenderer class instead of QgsMapSettings (see inline comments what has to be changed to try this) but the result is the same.

Any suggestions what I am missing here?

Comment: Uhm, I wrote the example above with QGIS dev 2.5 dbed468. I just tried to run it with QGIS 2.4.0 Chugiak and it works like it is supposed to :-O

Still, I appreciate any suggestions what has to be changed to make this run on QGIS 2.5 so I can still use it with QGIS 2.6 when it is released.

Meanwhile, I found out that with QGIS 2.6, `QgsComposerLegend.model()` is deprecated in favor of `QgsComposerLegend.modelV2()`, see [the API docs](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendModelV2.html). Maybe this is the new way to go? However, I could not manage yet to make it work this way...

Comment: mapRenderer is deprecated in `2.4` and above see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/223127/36886

Comment: Not an answer (mods please allow) but just happened on this thread whilst looking to export just a legend. Made light of what I though was going to be lots of hours/lines so thanks primarily to the OP and also those that answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your comment above, for QGIS 2.6 you can do something like this to insert a layer into the legend model:

```
   #######
   # create legend
   #######
   composerLegend = QgsComposerLegend(comp)
   layerGroup = QgsLayerTreeGroup()
   layerGroup.insertLayer(0, the_layer)
   composerLegend.modelV2().setRootGroup(layerGroup)
```

Comment: Hooray! This makes it work under QGIS 2.6, showing only the desired layers in the legend instead of all, thank you.

Comment: composerLegend.modelV2().setRootGroup(layerGroup) Using Essen 2.14 on a Mac, this approach barely works. I get layers showing up but not the labels for groups/subgroups they're contained by.